# Are there any operations in Python which are guaranteed never to fail?

Tags: python, exception

In C++, in order for code to be robust in the presence of exceptions, it is often necessary to rely on the fact that a few simple operations are guaranteed never to fail (and hence never to throw an exception). Examples of these operations include assignment of integers and swapping of standard containers.

Are there any operations in Python which provide this no-fail guarantee?

Comment: To what extent do you control the arguments to those operations? I think it would be fair to say that `1+1` won't fail in any reasonable conditions.

Comment: @NPE: addition can fail for overridden `__add__`. I'm not sure if the `__add__` of Python's default integer type can fail.

Comment: Have a look at the Python byte codes and see how many raise an exception.

Comment: @Tinctorius: You can't override `__add__` for built-ins.

Comment: I'd wager you could get a `MemoryError` at virtually any point. @TimPietzcker?

Comment: As a newbie programmer who's done a fair bit of Python but only ever glanced at C++ in passing, I'd never even heard of exception guarantees, but now that I've looked them up, I'm not sure they're too relevant to a Python setting. Their place in C++ development seems to relate to avoiding memory leaks or variables storing non-legal values? Those aren't issues in Python (well, mostly; some buggy C extensions can leak), so I think it's mostly a moot point? Anyway, my best guess is there are no no-fail guarantees for anything besides perhaps assignment to an existing name of an existing object.

Comment: Anything else, as @phant0m suggests, seems - to my naive eyes - likely to be capable of causing a MemoryError; even a function call is going to require creating some new names and assigning object references to them, which is presumably going to use some extra memory somewhere. But then, I've never looked at Python's internals, so this is just speculation.

Comment: @Ben Fails if there is no global name `Exception` (can happen if it's deleted from `__builtin__` or whatever it's called) and an exception is raised. In Python 3, it also fails if the name `Exception` refers to something that's not a type derived from (the builtin class usually known as) `BaseException`, for example an integer.

Comment: True @delnan; I should have written `except BaseException`, though I suspect even that can be overwritten?

Comment: @Ben Yeah, same problems apply unaltered.

Answer (score 3):

Python is a higher-level language than C and C++.  Anything can involve code execution behind the scenes, and no name is exempt from looking up its current, possibly overridden value.  It might be possible to identify some operations that are guaranteed never to raise an exception, but I suspect that set of operations would be so small that it provides no benefit over the usual assumption that anything can raise an exception at any time.

And the identification of those operations would require limiting your Python environment.  For example, you can assign a trace function which is invoked for every line of your Python program.  With a suitably crafted trace function, even 1+1 could raise an exception.  So do we assume that there is no trace function?  What about redefining builtins?

Practically speaking, you need to adopt a different mindset for Python: exceptions happen, and you can't know ahead of time what they might be.  As Mark Amery says in the comments, C++ needs to avoid memory leaks and uninitialized variables, which are not issues in Python.